# shiny app File Upload: How can we save the files uploaded on a shiny GUI to a particular destination?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a GUI using shiny to take 5 files as an input. Once I have uploaded these files, I want them to be saved in a particular Folder whose destination is known by me. Can we do this? If yes, how? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, kind of. You can use observer to copy the file on upload:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui=shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
       fileInput("upload", "Upload", multiple = FALSE)
    )),

    server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session){               
        observe({
            if (is.null(input$upload)) return()
            file.copy(input$upload$datapath, "/some/other/path")
        })
    })
)
```

Not that I am using `file.copy` and not `file.rename` to avoid problems when the destination is located on a different device than the temporary directory.

Comment: Is there a way to do this to export the data directly to dropbox? With `library(rdrop2)`?
`outputDir <- "responses"
epochTime <- function() {as.integer(Sys.time())}
humanTime <- function() {format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d-%H%M%OS")}
saveData <- function(data) {
  data = c(data, timestamp = epochTime())
  data <- t(data)
  fileName <- sprintf("evo_rates_form_%s_%s.csv", 
                      humanTime(), 
                      digest::digest(data))
  filePath <- file.path(tempdir(), 
                        fileName)
  drop_upload(filePath, 
              dest = outputDir)
}`

Comment: @zero323, which path [ file.copy(input$upload$datapath, "????")] can we give once we deploy the app ?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by **zero323**, Use `file.copy` as below if you want to overwrite the old uploads with new ones during each re-run of your app:

```
file.copy(..., recursive= TRUE)
```

(I wanted this in my app but it took me a whole lot of time to figure this out as I was a newbie at this)