# Shiny fileInput Does Not Keep File Name

Tags: r, file-upload, upload, shiny

I am writing a program in Shiny where the user uploads a file and it saves to a specified folder. The method to do this is taken from [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966924/shiny-app-file-upload-how-can-we-save-the-files-uploaded-on-a-shiny-gui-to-a-pa).

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui=shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
       fileInput("upload", "Upload", multiple = FALSE)
    )),

    server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session){               
        observe({
            if (is.null(input$upload)) return()
            file.copy(input$upload$datapath, "/some/other/path")
        })
    })
)
```

When I execute this, I find that the file has its file name stripped when it is saved to the specified folder. The program that reads the files in the folder requires that the file name is left in tact. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Could you give an example? What was the original name and what was the stripped name?

Comment: It is literally any name and it will get stripped to '0'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the file.copy line to

```
file.copy(input$upload$datapath, paste0("your_folder/", input$upload$name))
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify a file on dropbox like using `drop_upload` or it can only copy fiels on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

This works well: rename the files locally and then upload them via a forloop and then remove the local files. Here's some code that worked for me:

```
observe({
  if(!is.null(input$file_support)){
    browser()
    files = file.rename(input$file_support$datapath, paste0(input$file_support$name))
    files = paste0(input$file_support$name)
    n_files = length(files)
    for(i in 1:n_files){
      drop_upload(files[i], dest = "drop_test")
    }
  file.remove(files)
  }
  })

})
```