# How to upload file in www folder via Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want my file to be uploaded in www folder in Shiny. I'm uploading by using this code, but it is not uploading file in www folder. Do anyone know how can I do this? My OS is Windows. I am using this code:

This is "ui.R":

```
fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ',')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('contents')
    )
  )
)
```

This is "server.R":

```
# By default, the file size limit is 5MB. It can be changed by
# setting this option. Here we'll raise limit to 9MB.
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)

function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
  })
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shiny app File Upload: How can we save the files uploaded on a shiny GUI to a particular destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966924/shiny-app-file-upload-how-can-we-save-the-files-uploaded-on-a-shiny-gui-to-a-pa)